# Can't set custom configuration file for mysql docker container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, kitematic, docker-desktop

I am using the **Mysql image** (https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mysql/). I want to use a custom conf file to override the sql mode but I am having some difficulties.

[image]

When I click on the first line, where the change button is, it displays like there is no file in that folder but there is a `my.cnf` file there.

Do I need to make additional changes somewhere?

To run/start the container I used this command `docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag` but with my data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the permissions on the conf file.